# Permissão do Apache no Windows 7

Tags: apache

Instalei o Apache (versão 2.2.25) no Windows 7 e alterei a pasta padrão do `DocumentRoot` para `c:\tmp`.

Fiz a seguinte alteração no arquivo `httpd.conf`:

```
#DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs"
DocumentRoot "C:/tmp"
```

Após essa mudança reiniciei o computador e tentei acessar a pasta pelo browser.

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Como resolver esse problema?

Comment: Tem um index.html ou index.htm nessa pasta?

Comment: A pasta existe e possui um arquivo index.html

Comment: O apache está rodando como service ou standalone?

Comment: Como sei a diferença?

Comment: @Lucas aperte a tecla windows, digite services.msc e dê enter. Aí veja se na lista de serviços tem o Apache e se ele está rodando. (Se você precisa clicar nele pra ele rodar, ou pôs atalho na pasta iniciar, provavelmente não está como serviço). Dá pra usar dos dois jeitos, mas as permissões mudam um pouco. É pra ambiente de testes só?

Comment: Fiz o que disse e vi o Apache na lista com o status de "Iniciado" e no Tipo de Inicialização está "Automático"

Comment: Ok, entao está como service mesmo. Provavelmente basta acertar as permissões da pasta, com botão direito nela, na aba segurança, e acrescentar o usuário do apache. Apertando Control + Shift + Esc, na aba Processos, apertando "mostrar processos de todos os usuários" você ve as credenciais do Apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No arquivo `httpd.conf` procure pela seguinte entrada:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all          # linha padrão, geralmente causa do problema
</Directory>
```

Troque a linha em questão para:

```
Allow from all
```

Isso fará com que o apache fique acessível para todas as máquinas da sua rede (e para fora se seu roteador estiver fazendo *port fowarding*). Se você quiser restringir apenas acesso local use:

```
Deny from all 
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Outro ponto importante são as permissões de usuário conforme comentários do Bacco. Além das permissões da pasta é bom verificar o usuário de *Log On* do serviço em:

```
services.msc -> Apache -> (Duplo Clique) -> Aba Log On
```

Por *default* esse deve ser um usuário do sistema local. Nesse caso é recomendável que o `httd.conf` contenha as configurações:

```
User daemon
Group daemon
```

**P.S.** É claro esse não é o melhor *setup* em termos de segurança. É recomendável criar um usuário não administrador dedicado ao servidor (e.g., `apache`), conceder à esse usuário privilégios para que ele possa logar como um serviço e atuar como parte do sistema operacional (em `secpol.msc`) e garantir permissões de acesso de forma consciente apenas para as pastas necessárias.

---

**Fontes**:

- [SOen - Error message “Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295)
- [Apache HTTP Server Version 2.2 - Using Apache HTTP Server on Microsoft Windows](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/platform/windows.html)